# Direct hibernate native query is working fine but query with setParameter is not updating postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, orm

**Not working**

```
    String sql = "UPDATE xsp_job_request SET xsp_job_status_id = 2 , xsp_job_id = :xspJobId WHERE xsp_job_request_id = :xspJobRequestId AND xsp_job_status_id = 1";

 Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
 query.setParameter("xspJobId", jobId);
 query.setParameter("xspJobRequestId", jobRequestId);
 affectedRows = query.executeUpdate();
```

**Working. But need to use namedParameter query**

```
String sql = "UPDATE xsp_job_request SET xsp_job_status_id = 2 , xsp_job_id = '7884ed98-972a-46c8-ae22-e4f445b4568' WHERE xsp_job_request_id = '8fa2c5e46638ad66016638adab060000' AND xsp_job_status_id = 1";
 Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
 affectedRows = query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: And you don't get error messages from the first one? Try calling `entityManager.flush()` before creating and after executing the query. It may help reveal the cause of problem.

Comment: There was no error. Even after adding entityManager.flush() before and after  query.executeUpdate()

Comment: Other than simply having no rows that match the criteria, I don't see a reason for this not to work. No error means the query parsed, the table and columns used exist, and both parameters are set before execution, and the flush guarantees the query completed. The problem may be in the data, not in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the assignment sign as `:=` colon and equal without a space in between.

```
String sql = "UPDATE xsp_job_request SET xsp_job_status_id = 2, xsp_job_id =:xspJobId WHERE xsp_job_request_id =:xspJobRequestId AND xsp_job_status_id = 1";
```

Comment: := or =:  which one?

Comment: := or =:  which one?

Comment: it throws error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [UPDATE xsp_job_request SET xsp_job_status_id = 2 , xsp_job_id =: xspJobId WHERE xsp_job_request_id =: xspJobRequestId AND xsp_job_status_id = 1]

Comment: Edited my answer with new query